# Compiling GLUT using Emscripten

Tags: javascript, c++, emscripten

I am trying to compile the following code:
http://pastebin.com/024Ew4fK

And I am using the following directives:
-s LEGACY_GL_EMULATION=1 -lglut -lGLU -lGL

I got the following warnings:

```
warning: unresolved symbol: glPointSize
warning: unresolved symbol: glutSolidSphere
warning: unresolved symbol: glutWireSphere
```

And these are the errors:

```
WARNING: using emscripten GL immediate mode emulation. This is very limited in what it supports

missing function: glPointSize

uncaught exception: abort(-1) at jsStackTrace@file:///C:/Users/Tyrion/Documents/Proyectos/GLUT_SolarSystem/out.js:1173:13
stackTrace@file:///C:/Users/Tyrion/Documents/Proyectos/GLUT_SolarSystem/out.js:1190:22
abort@file:///C:/Users/Tyrion/Documents/Proyectos/GLUT_SolarSystem/out.js:15901:44
_glPointSize@file:///C:/Users/Tyrion/Documents/Proyectos/GLUT_SolarSystem/out.js:2135:56
_main@file:///C:/Users/Tyrion/Documents/Proyectos/GLUT_SolarSystem/out.js:11483:2
asm._main@file:///C:/Users/Tyrion/Documents/Proyectos/GLUT_SolarSystem/out.js:15672:8
callMain@file:///C:/Users/Tyrion/Documents/Proyectos/GLUT_SolarSystem/out.js:15766:15
doRun@file:///C:/Users/Tyrion/Documents/Proyectos/GLUT_SolarSystem/out.js:15824:42
run/<@file:///C:/Users/Tyrion/Documents/Proyectos/GLUT_SolarSystem/out.js:15835:7
setTimeout handler*run@file:///C:/Users/Tyrion/Documents/Proyectos/GLUT_SolarSystem/out.js:15831:5
@file:///C:/Users/Tyrion/Documents/Proyectos/GLUT_SolarSystem/out.js:15927:1
```

Why does it say that glPointSize is missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the features of Glut supported by Emscripten:
https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/blob/master/src/library_glut.js

In order to draw something, for example a sphere, Kripken suggested somewhere to look for a function written in C that does it by itself and then, to port that function to my program.

Comment: for reference, this is where he suggested it: https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/issues/1929